# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser return all list items

Tags: php, parsing, dom

I am currently working with PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser trying to scrape a site. Here is what i have so far:

```
$html = file_get_html('https://www.example.com');

// Find all article blocks
foreach($html->find('.plan') as $article) {
    $item['title']     = $article->find('.price', 0)->plaintext;
    $item['intro']   = $article->find('li', 0)->plaintext;
    $item['details'] = $article->find('.button', 0)->href;
    $articles[] = $item;
}

print_r($articles);
```

The above works fine, however if more than one `<li>` exists it only returns the first `<li>` missing out the rest.

Is there a way i can get all list items?

Answer (score 1):

With the second attribute in the find-function, you define the nth element of the result, that should be returned. In your example, `$article->find('li',0)` gives you the li element at index 0 (so the first) of the matching elements.

If you want all `<li>` elements, try this:

```
$html = file_get_html('https://www.example.com');

// Find all article blocks
foreach($html->find('.plan') as $article) {
    $item['title']   = $article->find('.price', 0)->plaintext;
    $item['intro']   = array(); //define as array
    foreach ($article->find('li') as $li) { //get all <li>-elements as array
        $item['intro'][] = $li->plaintext; //add the plaintext of each single <li> element as new position to the $item['intro'] array
    }
    $item['details'] = $article->find('.button', 0)->href;
    $articles[] = $item;
}

print_r($articles);
```